# Mobile-Friendly errors from JS/CSS folders in Google Search Console

Tags: google-search-console, javascript, css, mobile, assets

Google Search Console is warning me about Mobile Friendly errors. But all the errors are coming from the assets folder where I keep my CSS and JS files. Can anyone can help explain these errors?

[image]

Comment: @Vivoth Are the errors on the actual `.js` and `.css` files themselves, or only on the folder containing them? It could be that your server is serving a directory listing when you go to the folder's URL, and the directory listing page itself is not mobile-friendly.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister,  It's not about .js or .css file error.  It could be the server is serving a directory listing when I go to the folder's URL it list all file in directory. If so, what is the best practice to solve the problem ?

Comment: @Vivoth The simplest solution would be to disable directory listing for those folders. The process is different depending on what web server software you are using, but try Google searching "disable directory listing [name of server]".

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister, I will try to use .htaccess file to disable it. I will get back if it work. Thank for your comment

Comment: @Vivoth From my quick Google search, you should have `Options -Indexes` in the `.htaccess` file at the root of your website.

Comment: @Vivoth Unfortunately as it is, this is still too broad to answer without more specific details, We see these types of errors often, however they really depend on the code you're using. It also appears you have a question about whether it's coming from a directory listing, and seem to be satisfied with Maximillian Laumeister's suggestion above. If not, you can edit the question to add more details and will be added back to the review queue for consideration to be reopened.